# Config setting clarification

Tags: config

Is there a difference between the config variables $config['compress_output'] and $config['gzip_output']?

I was getting some errors with a particular add-on while having $config['compress_output']= FALSE; set in config.php. Adding $config['gzip_output'] = "n"; to config.php made the error go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the same setting actually. 
In case if you have gzip_output = y, compress_output will be = TRUE.
I think it possible some legacy from EE1 (gzip_output) and and CI (compress_output)

**EE_Output.php**:

```
// Compress the output
// We simply set the ci config value to true

if ($EE->config->item('gzip_output') == 'y' AND REQ == 'PAGE')
{
    $EE->config->set_item('compress_output', TRUE);
}
```

Comment: Very odd then. I need $config['gzip_output'] = "n"; in my config.php file to avoid an error I'm getting with a particular add-on.

Having just $config['compress_output']= FALSE; without also having $config['gzip_output'] = "n"; results in an error. Deleting $config['compress_output']= FALSE; but keeping $config['gzip_output'] = "n"; also works.

I wonder if it's an EE bug?

Comment: in what add-ons have this error?

Comment: Messaging http://www.intoeetive.com/index.php/comments/messaging

Comment: It possible that may be some add-ons can switch it. I check different version of EE and I can't find any other place where gzip_output can be setup except config.php & EE_Output.php. May be you have gzip_output = "y" somewhere in other files, like index.php. But it is odd.

Comment: Well, it's not set in index.php anywhere and I searched through the Messaging addon files and found no mention of gzip or compression. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that EE requires gzip_output to be set and not compress_output. There are several places in the EE system files that are using/referencing gzip_output but make no mention of compress_output, most tellingly in Template.php. Compress_output may be limited to just CodeIgniter itself.

expressionengine/libraries/Template.php

```
2869        // GZip mode: {gzip_mode}
2870:       $str = str_replace(LD.'gzip_mode'.RD, ($this->EE->config->item('gzip_output') == 'y') ? $this->EE->lang->line('enabled') : $this->EE->lang->line('disabled'), $str);
2871                
2872        // App version: {version}
```

expressionengine/models/admin_model.php

```
75              'output_cfg'        =>  array(
76                  'send_headers'              => array('r', array('y' => 'yes', 'n' => 'no')),
77:                 'gzip_output'               => array('r', array('y' => 'yes', 'n' => 'no')),
78                  'force_query_string'        => array('r', array('y' => 'yes', 'n' => 'no')),
79                  'redirect_method'           => array('s', array('redirect' => 'location_method', 'refresh' => 'refresh_method')),

258                         'template_debugging'        => array('template_debugging_explanation'),
259                         'max_caches'                => array('max_caches_explanation'),
260:                        'gzip_output'               => array('gzip_output_explanation'),
261                         'server_offset'             => array('server_offset_explain'),
262                         'default_member_group'      => array('group_assignment_defaults_to_two'),
```